# Python dictionary print with parentheses

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to edit this function so the values of the dictionary will not be printed in parentheses and will be iterable:

```
def traverse_appended(key):
reg_dict = {}
#keypath = r"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"
for item in traverse_reg(key):
    keypath_str = str(keypath+item)
    reg_dict[item] = str(get_reg("Displayversion", keypath_str)), str(get_reg("DisplayName", keypath_str))
    #reg_dict[item] = get_reg("DisplayName", keypath_str)

return reg_dict
```

the expected output is :

```
{'DXM_Runtime': 'None', 'None'}
```

The function output:

```
{'DXM_Runtime': ('None', 'None')}
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. They are in paranthesis since they are tuple.

Comment: The function returns a dictionary, not a string. You don't show where you're printing it, but this is the way dictionaries are printed by default in Python. If you really want to print it with different (ambiguous) formatting, you just need to write your own code to do so, then pass the dictionary to that code. If it's just for debugging, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Consider traverse_appended returns following dict.
#I think, converting func_dict values which are tuple into string, will help you to get expected  output.

func_dict = {"DXM_Runtime":('None','None'),
             "TMP_KEY":('A','B')
             }

derived_dict = {}
for k,v in func_dict.viewitems():
    tmp_str = ",".join(v)
    derived_dict[k] = tmp_str

print derived_dict

#Output

E:\tmp_python>python tmp.py

{'DXM_Runtime': 'None,None', 'TMP_KEY': 'A,B'}

#If this doesn't help you, then please post the code for get_reg and traverse_reg function also.
```